# Eclipse not seeing java file properties

Tags: java, properties, resourcebundle

I'm doing internationalisation in Java.

I've created two files: `MessageBundle_en_US.properties` and `MessageBundle_en_IN.properties`.

**`MessageBundle_en_US.properties`**:

```
greeting=Hello, how are you?
```

**`MessageBundle_en_IN.properties`**

```
greeting=Halo, apa
```

And finally, here's the main class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class InternationalizationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ResourceBundle bundle =
            ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle", Locale.US);
        
        System.out.println(
            "Message in "
          + Locale.US
          + ": "
          + bundle.getString("greeting")
        );
        
        //changing the default locale to indonasian
        Locale.setDefault(new Locale("in", "ID"));
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("MessageBundle");
        
        System.out.println(
            "Message in "
          + Locale.getDefault()
          + ": "
          + bundle.getString("greeting")
        );
    }
}
```

And I receive the following error stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name MessageBundle, locale en_US
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:2055)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1689)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1593)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1556)
    at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:932)
    at provame.InternationalizationDemo.main(InternationalizationDemo.java:8)
```

**UPDATE**
I've found the reason it was unable to see the file, first of all you need to put *properties file in the same directory as the main class, as the kind people suggested in the comments, and you should adjust the call to the file like that:

```
projectName/propertiesFileName
```

This was all.

Comment: Have you placed your `*.properties` files in the same directory as `InternationalizationDemo.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place your `*.properties` files in the same folder as `InternationalizationDemo.java`
2. Rename: `MessageBundle_en_IN.properties` to: `MessageBundle_in_ID.properties`